# Flatten and map objects inner collection to another collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a **source** enumeration which holds an inner enumeration, *IEnumerable<>.*  I want to be able to take my sources inner enumeration and flatten it out into my destination enumeration.  However, when I attempt the following code below, I am prompted with an exception stating that this is an invalid mapping.

```
public class DestinationClass 
{
   string Name {get; set;}
}

public class SourceClass
{
   IEnumerable<SourceInnerClass> InnerCollection {get; set;}
}

public class SourceInnerClass
{
   string Name {get; set;}
}

// Mapping Configuration

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceInnerClass, DestinationClass>();

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, IEnumerable<DestinationClass>>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(source => source.InnerCollection));

// Implementation

IEnumeration<SourceClass> sourceCollection = GetSourceDataEnumeration();

var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumeration<DestinationClass>>(sourceCollection);
```

I've tried many different variations of the code above, and I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  I'm either prompted that I cannot map at a "parent level" or that the mapping does not exist.

If I were manually mapping, I would essentially want to do the following, however, auto mapper complains this construction is invalid:

```
var destination = source.InnerCollection.Select(s => new DestinationClass { Name = s.Name }
```

The exact error I get is,

> Additional information: Custom configuration for members is only
>   supported for top-level individual members on a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to keep the enumerable out of the CreateMap definition...keep that type based for a single object.

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<SourceInnerClass, DestinationClass>();

    var results = sourceCollection.SelectMany(sm=>sm.InnerCollection).Select(s=>Mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(s));
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much exactly what I did.  The trick was doing a SelectMany on the inner collection prior to calling the mapper.

Comment: Another more obscure way of using SelectMany is sourceCollection.SelectMany(sm=>sm.InnerColletion,(ic,s)=>Mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(s)) where 'ic' represents each inner collection.  It basically smooshes SelectMany and Select into one statement.  Usually for clarity I prefer the version I originally wrotebecause I don' t need access to the per-object collection.